# AEM 6.1: How to get component included with data-sly-resource in SlingFilter?

Tags: aem, sling

I have a page component (/libs/wcm/foundation/components/page) with other included components like:

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${'search' @ resourceType='/apps/project/components/search'}" sly/>
```

How can I get a list of these components in a Sling Filter? I tried to use scope SlingFilterScope.COMPONENT, but all components included with data-sly-resource are ignored and I get only components added to parsys.

Comment: Did you try scope as `INCLUDE`? As per the documentation INCLUDE and FORWARD filters are also called if the respective including (e.g. <jsp:include> or <sling:include>) or forwarding (e.g. <jsp:forward> or <sling:forward>) ultimately calls the RequestDispatcher. So, not sure if they are calling the request dispatcher, but in case they do, you should be able to access them.

Comment: what do you mean by "How can I get a list of these components in a Sling Filter" are you looking for ALL components included on the page with a `data-sly-resource` ?